# Xamarin.Forms - Center View on Entry

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I've got a simple Xamarin.Forms App where there is an Entry at the lower bottom of the View. The Problem is that when the user taps the Entry to edit the text inside, the overlaying Scrollview scrolls up to still show the Entry, but the Keyboard is getting displayed above of the Entry, not completely, but enough to annoy.

[image: Non-Keyboard Mode]

[image: With Keyboard]

I bet this is because of the Entry having a different height than the unedited one. Is there a way to make the Scrollview scroll a little bit more to show the Entry in full height + some delta pixels?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you show us the code how you scroll Scrollview when the keyboard appears.

Comment: I did not code any code for this functionality. I think this is automatically added with Xamarin.Forms